# Trigger .exe upon receiving email from sender

Tags: c#, vba, api, outlook

I've written a C# application with .net framework. The purpose is to request data from an online spreadsheet app, do stuff with it, then send back updated data.

I think the best way to trigger the exe would be to use webhooks/callbacks, but I gather this would require runnning my program on a web sever with an external IP address.

Rather than periodically polling the spreadsheet app I would like the app to send emails to a specified account upon certain data changes. Upon receiving the email, VBA code checks that the email is from the app then runs the executable.

To run exe on receipt of email:

```
Private Sub Application_NewMail()
 Dim path As String
 Dim shl As Variant
 path = "C:\Users\***\Desktop\SmartPlugin.exe"
 shl = Shell(path, 1)
End Sub
```

How do I check the sender? The examples I found online loop through all emails but what I'm after is a method of returning the last email received.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working.

```vb
Private Sub Application_NewMail()

    Dim objN As NameSpace
    Dim objF As MAPIFolder

    Set objN = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objF = objN.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set mlItems = objF.Items
    mlItems.Sort "CreationTime", True
    Set mlItem = mlItems.Item(1)

    Dim path As String
    Dim shl As Variant
    Dim sndString As String
    sndString = CStr(mlItem.SenderName)
    
    If InStr(1, sndString, "SmartSheet", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
        path = "C:\Users\Alex Rose\Desktop\SmartPlugin.exe"
        shl = Shell(path, 1)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This will not work if you have multiple emails arriving - you will keep getting the same latest email, which might not event be the email that has just arrived - see my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Application.NewMailEx` event instead - it passes the entry id of the new message as the parameter. Use that entry id to call `Application.Session.GetItemfromID`.